# which one is efficiency of linear and binary search

Tags: java

```
public enum Color {
    Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Purple;


    private boolean isRGB(Color color)
    {


    boolean b;

    switch(color){
        case Red:
            System.out.println("Monday is a work day!!");
            break;
        case Orange:
            System.out.println("Tusday is a work day!!");
        case Yellow:
            System.out.println("Wednesday is a work day!!");
        case Green:
            System.out.println("Thursday is a work day!!");
        case Cyan:
            System.out.println("Friday is a work day!!");   
        default:   b = false;

        System.out.println("Sorry this is not a working day!!\nn");
        System.out.println("It's weekend!!!");
    }
    return(b);
}
```

This is the code i tried myself.
I have one error in the return(b), says that 'b' is not initialized....help please.

Comment: can some one help me to figure out what i'm doing wrong!!!

Comment: THIS IS THE EXERCISE QUESTION IF NEED IT""........Write a program to check whether it is one of three primitive colors(Red Green Blue, RGB. That Monday , Tuesday,……Friday are work days.

Comment: What does this have to do with the title of your question?

Comment: Hint: what do you believe the value of `b` will be if `color` is `Red`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
boolean b;
```

with

```
boolean b = true;
```

Comment: @TobiasWürth: Again, untrue for local variables. Only *fields* are initialized  by default.

Answer (score -2):

`public enum Color{//......` - the dots were added by the teacher but nothing was asking to add.

```
public enum Color {
    Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Purple;    
}

private boolean isRGB(Color color) {

    boolean b = false;

    switch (color) {// i supposed to fill the blank switch(        )
        //And also i supposed write  all the statements for switch, thats all was required me to do!!
        case Red:
            System.out.println("Monday is a work day!!");
            break;
        case Orange:
            System.out.println("Tusday is a work day!!");
            break;
        case Yellow:
            System.out.println("Wednesday is a work day!!");
            break;
        case Green:
            System.out.println("Thursday is a work day!!");
            break;
        case Cyan:
            System.out.println("Friday is a work day!!");
            break;

        default:
            b = false;

            System.out.println("Sorry this is not a working day!!\nn");
            System.out.println("It's weekend!!!");

    }
    return (b);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. If you want to edit your question, hit the "edit" link.